# getting different scrollWidth on FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I have an angular directive that shows/hides scrolling buttons on tabset.

[image]

I'm trying to show/hide the buttons based on element width calculation. The problem is I'm getting different values on FF/Chrome.

```
function _setArrowsVisibility() {
                var scrollWidth = tabs.prop('scrollWidth');
                var width = tabs.innerWidth();
                console.log('scrollWidth:', scrollWidth);
                console.log('width:', width);
                tabs.css('max-width', angular.element(elm).innerWidth() - 168);

                //fix for IE11 (on IE11 we get scrollWidth = 260 , width = 259)
                if (scrollWidth - width > 0 && scrollWidth - width - 1 > 0) {
                    leftBtn.css('display', '');
                    rightBtn.css('display', '');
                    _updateButtons();
                }
                else {
                    leftBtn.css('display', 'none');
                    rightBtn.css('display', 'none');
                }

        }
```

On FF i get : **scrollWidth: 1006** , **width: 985**

On chrome i get : **scrollWidth: 987** , **width: 987**

The wanted outcome is the one i get on chrome.

Comment: hmm something that can make us able to repro the issue?

Comment: @Kaiido - Unfortunately no :(  It's part of a large ,complicated structure and when i try to dumb it down for a simple plunkr, it's working fine